# Adding 2 Functions to One Click

Tags: jquery

I have this code I've written, It's for a form, and it copies information from the top of the form to the bottom if a checkbox is clicked, and then changes it if any information is changed in the top form.  Now I want to make the bottom form un-editable by the user if the checkbox is clicked, and leave the top one accessible, but I want to do it within the same click statement.  The way I had it written entirely disabled the functionality, I had, and I was wondering if anyone could chime in with any ideas on how to resolve this...

```
 $("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").click(function(){ 
    if ($("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) 
    { 
        // Checked, copy values 
        $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($("#Referral_Address_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($("#Referral_City_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToState_T").val($("#Referral_State_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToZip_T").val($("#Referral_Zip_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T,#Referral_PayToCity_T,#_Referral_PayToState_T,#Referral_PayToZip_T").val('').attr('editable', false);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Clear on uncheck 
        $("#Referral_Address_T").val(""); 
        $("#Referral_City_T").val(""); 
        $("#Referral_State_T").val(""); 
        $('#Referral_PayToAddress_T,#Referral_PayToCity_T,#_Referral_PayToState_T,#Referral_PayToZip_T').attr('editable', true);
    } 
});
```

Comment: in your if statement.. right after you set the values.. you are setting them back to empty right before you make editable false `.val('').attr('editable', false);`

Comment: What functionality got disabled? and what is/isn't it doing that it's supposed to

Comment: I edited the quotation marks out, which brought back the original functionality, but did not disable the editable nature of the statement.   Is there something else I'm not doing to achieve that functionality?

Comment: When it was originally written it wouldn't copy down the data when checked.  When I took the quotes out it would then copy down, and change the information in the form.

Comment: you can take the .val() out of that line actually.. it's not used for anything.. also you should probably use `readonly` or `disabled` for instead of `editable` I'm not even sure if that attribute exists

Comment: Sometimes I had troubles with setting editable to false, as jquery didn't seem to recognize the "false" argument. Try to remove the whole "editable" attribute: `$("#fields").removeAttr("editable");`

Comment: I got it working to a point.  I switched editable to readonly as suggested, and there was a minor syntax error an underscore before _Referral_PayToState_T

Now PaytoState is a pull down menu with encompasses all 50 states, and then Zip is a just a simple text field.  readonly is set to false, and it works for address and city I put in my address, city, state, zip to test.  It locks down the address and city just fine, but will still allow me to change the zip and state.  Any idea why those limitations would be there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use  .attr('readonly', true);  AND  .attr('readonly', false);

```
 $("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").click(function() {
        if ($("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) {
            // Checked, copy values 
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($("#Referral_Address_T").val());
            $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($("#Referral_City_T").val());
            $("#Referral_PayToState_T").val($("#Referral_State_T").val());
            $("#Referral_PayToZip_T").val($("#Referral_Zip_T").val());
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T,#Referral_PayToCity_T,#Referral_PayToState_T,#Referral_PayToZip_T").prop('readonly', true);
        }
        else {
            // Clear on uncheck 
            $("#Referral_Address_T").val("");
            $("#Referral_City_T").val("");
            $("#Referral_State_T").val("");
            $("#Referral_Zip_T").val("");
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T,#Referral_PayToCity_T,#Referral_PayToState_T,#Referral_PayToZip_T").prop('readonly', false);
        }
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/q7f9a/1/)

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/q7f9a/3/)

Comment: Why did you use .prop rather than .attr? Also, I'm still having the last 2 feels editable with either.

Comment: You can use either of them.. But the suggested method is to use .prop

Comment: Does that fact that it's state is a pull down menu have anything to do with it?

Comment: Weird, this is very bothersome then.

Comment: What exactly is happening in your page... Can you reproduce it in a fiddle so that I can have a look

Comment: How do I set up a fiddle?  Basically everything works, form duplicates information and changes just fine. It is readonly for address and city, but not for state and zip.

Comment: I only posted my Click Code

Here is the change code, and maybe something in here is causing it...
$("#Referral_Address_T,#Referral_City_T,#Referral_State_T,#Referral_Zip_T").change(function(){
    if ($("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) 
        { 
            // Checked, copy values 
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($("#Referral_Address_T").val()); 
            $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($("#Referral_City_T").val()); 
          $("#Referral_PayToState_T").val($("#Referral_State_T").val()); 
$("#Referral_PayToZip_T").val($("#Referral_Zip_T").val()); 
        }